# How to allocate pinned memory to a 2-dimensional array using CudaMallocHost?

Tags: cuda, dynamic-memory-allocation

How to allocate pinned memory to a 2-dimensional array using CudaMallocHost?

Looking forward to any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Host) memory is one-dimensional. Just like you allocate `n * m * sizeof(T)` bytes for a two-dimensional, n-by-m, array of type-T elements, with `malloc()` (or `new[]`, or `std::make_unique()`) - you do the same with `cudaMallocHost()`.

Now, it's true that the above is not the only way to model a two-dimensional array. As explained in the [C FAQ, question 6.16](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html), we may sometimes use an array-of-pointers, each of which points to a 1-D array of the minor dimension. This too can be done using `cudaMallocHost()` - again, by simply substituting it for `malloc()`. However, note this indirection has a performance penalty.

<sub>If you want array rows to be nicely-aligned, you might want to pad each row with some unused elements; but that's again true both for regular host-side memory allocation and for `cudaMallocHost()`.</sub>

Comment: well, for a 2d-array, if I use  malloc(), for example: 
`int **arr = (int **)malloc(n*sizeof(int *));  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
     arr[i] = (int *)malloc(m*sizeof(int));}`

for cudaMallocHost(), by 

` cudaMallocHost((void**)&arr, sizeof(int)*n);
    for (int i = 0; i < ns; ++i) {
        cudaMallocHost((void**)&arr[i], sizeof(int)*m); }`   is right?

Comment: Yes, but - if you look at the FAQ, you'll notice that you don't need repeated malloc calls for each row. Just malloc the full thing once, then partition it into rows (i.e. use offsets into the larger allocation).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!